# Swift: AVAudioPlayer using array suddenly mutes

Tags: arrays, swift, avaudioplayer

I've written a small class that uses AVFoundation to play audio using an array. Basically an new element is appended to the array every time 'playAudio' is called. This allows multiple sounds to play without cutting each other off. Also, so that the array doesn't infinitely increase in size I've set it to cycle back to index 0 after filling 5 slots in the array. Now everything works perfectly but after 'audioPlayer' has been called a bunch of times, audio suddenly stops and I start getting the 'Error' in the Catch section but my app continues to function normally as if it has just been muted. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
var audioIndexA = 0
```

public class AudioPlayer: NSObject {

```
var playerA = [AVAudioPlayer]()

func playAudio(audioFile audioFile: String){

    do{

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioFile, ofType:"wav")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        playerA.insert(try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, fileTypeHint: nil), atIndex: audioIndexA)
        playerA[audioIndexA].prepareToPlay()

        if audioIndexA < 5{

            playerA[audioIndexA].play()
            audioIndexA++

        } else{

            playerA[audioIndexA].play()
            audioIndexA = 0
        }

    } catch{

        print("Error")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider using AVQueuePlayer if you are tyring to queue multiple audio one after another.

Comment: I actually need the audio to be able to play simultaneously, so a queue wouldn't work here.

Comment: BUMP!! Any help would be great.

Comment: So, what is the behavior of AVQueuePlayer while playing sequences of audio. Why isnt AVQueuePlayer useful to you ?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne I haven't used AVQueuePlayer but from the documentation it looks like it allows you to queue multiple audio files and play them one after the other. My requirement is different. I'm working on a game that has nine pads, each mapped to a musical note. I need to be able to play 2 or more pad simultaneously or in very quick succession which means multiple audios files will nee to be played at the same time. A queue would mean I'm restricted to one at a time. I'm just trying to figure out why my code works perfectly for sometime but then stops.

Comment: ok, now I get it. So, then in that case the way that you did above is the good way to go.